# How to do a query string parsing into key value pair string from a HTML form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

In one of the web application I develop, I need to serialize the form and then split the query string into key value pairs as mentioned below.

```
    var frmSerialized=$(frm).serialize().replace(/\+/g,'%20');      //The jquery libraries upto version 2.0 converts spaces to plus
    var frmKeyPair=decodeURIComponent(frmSerialized).split("&");
```

Everything was working fine for me until I found two of the cases:

1. When one of the form element has a value which contains '&'. For example

   `<input name="fName" value="Sons & Co" type="hidden">`
2. When one of the form element has a value which contains '?'. For example

   `<input type="hidden" name="Questions" value = "A?b.=c">`

The form serialize and split process fails at these occurrences. What could be a better alternative in serializing and then splitting the query string?

**Edit**: The main purpose for this is to encrypt the parameters from preventing web parameter tampering. So what I do actually do is:

```
for(var j=0;j<frmKeyPair.length;j++){
        var mapInput;
        var element=frmKeyPair[j].split("=");
        var elemName=decodeURIComponent(element[0]);
        var eleValue=decodeURIComponent(element[1]);
        mapInput = document.createElement("input");
        mapInput.type = "hidden";
        mapInput.name = aesUtil.encrypt(salt, iv, passPhrase, elemName);
        mapInput.value = eleValue==null?"":aesUtil.encrypt(salt, iv, passPhrase, eleValue);
        mapForm.appendChild(mapInput);
    }
```

Here I use CryptoJS library that's available in GitHub. MapForm is a new dynamically created HTML Form. After the encryption is finished I submit it using

```
mapForm.submit();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can split by & to get they key value pairs, and then split those by '=' before decoding the value.

```js
var x = $( 'form' ).serialize().replace(/\+/g,'%20');

console.log( x );

x.split( '&' ).forEach(function(keyValue){
  var [ key, value ] = keyValue.split( '=' );
  
  console.log( key, ' = ', decodeURIComponent( value ) );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
<input name="fName" value="Sons & Co" type="hidden">
<input type="hidden" name="Questions" value = "A?b.=c">
</form>
```